# How can I add users and grant rights to database objects using code-first?

Tags: entity-framework-core, oracle-xe, oracle18c

Setting up a new Oracle XE database (using Entity Framework Core `dbContext.Database.EnsureCreated()`), I need to create db users and grant appropriate rights to them for all objects I create (e.g. entities, sequences etc., but also user permissions, like `CREATE SESSION` system privilege)

I've been looking for corresponding `ModelBuilder` extension methods, but couldn't find any.

How do I create users and grant privileges using EF Core Code-first?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this @AxD?

Comment: Yes, I created an EF add-in for that, supporting SQL Server and Oracle. It works splendidly, but I never had the time to create a NuGet package and publish it yet.

Comment: We just created an extension method in our project for the OperationBuilder, which allows you to pass in the table name database user name, and just executes the raw SQL with those parameters substituted in :)